# EntityManages NullPointerException, eclipselink + tomee + Jersey + Derby

Tags: java, rest, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am new to JPA, EJB and REST topic and wanted to make some simple crud app. When I use EntityManagerFactory I get entities from Derby but problem starts when I want to use transactions for persisting objects. When I try to inject EntityManager I get NullPointerException. I've seen several topic at stackOverflow with similar problems but apparently I cannot solve my problem.

I just want to run this app and focus on persistence concept and not spent another few days trying to set it up. Also I don't know why I cannot provide DataSource in WEB-INF/resources.xml (`WARNING - Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "Resource/Crud/localDB" not found.`)

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>localDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.kuba.crud.model.Customer</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testUser"/>  
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.target-database." value="Derby"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDB;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Customer entity

```
package com.kuba.crud.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByFirstname", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.firstname = :firstname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByLastname", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.lastname = :lastname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByAge", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.age = :age")})
public class Customer implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull   

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Integer age;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Customer)) {
            return false;
        }
        Customer other = (Customer) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.kuba.crud.model.Customer[ id=" + id + " first name="+firstname+" last name="+lastname+" age="+age+" ]";
    }



}
```

CustomerResource class

```
package com.kuba.crud.resources;

import com.kuba.crud.model.Customer;
import com.kuba.crud.service.CustomerService;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/customers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public class CustomerResource {

   @EJB(lookup = "CustomerService")
   private CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerResource() {

    }        

    @GET
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
                 System.out.println("Is CustomerService emptyy? "+(customerService==null));
        return customerService.getAllCustomers();

    }
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id){
        return customerService.getCustomer(id);
    }

    @POST
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        customerService.addProfile(customer);
    }       
}
```

CustomerService class

```
package com.kuba.crud.service;

import com.kuba.crud.model.Customer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;    

@Stateful    
    public class CustomerService {

    //    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPersistenceUnit")
        private EntityManager em;

        public CustomerService(){
    //       entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
    //       em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        }

        public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {

            List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("Is empty? "+(em==null));

                Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll", Customer.class);
                customers = query.getResultList();

            return customers;
        }

        public Customer getCustomer(int id){

            return em.find(Customer.class, id);   

        }
        public void addProfile(Customer customer) {

                em.persist(customer); 


            System.out.println("CustomerService: "+customer);

        }

    }
```

Tomee on startup:

```
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
INFO - Default JPA Provider changed to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
INFO - Server version:        Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.3 (7.0.1)
INFO - Server built:          Jun 9 2016 11:16:29 UTC
INFO - Server number:         8.5.3.0
INFO - OS Name:               Windows 8.1
INFO - OS Version:            6.3
INFO - Architecture:          amd64
INFO - Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre
INFO - JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
INFO - JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
INFO - CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1
INFO - CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1
INFO - Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\lib\openejb-javaagent.jar
INFO - Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
INFO - Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\conf\logging.properties
INFO - Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
INFO - Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1
INFO - Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1
INFO - Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\temp
INFO - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\idmu\common;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\polyspace\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin;C:\Java\tomcat-native-1.2.8-win32-src;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;.
INFO - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
INFO - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO - Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
INFO - Startup: Wed Sep 07 13:11:16 CEST 2016
INFO - Copyright 1999-2016 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
INFO - Version: 7.0.1
INFO - Build date: 20160623
INFO - Build time: 12:04
INFO - ********************************************************************************
INFO - openejb.home = C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1
INFO - openejb.base = C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1
INFO - Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@6d2a209c
INFO - Succeeded in installing singleton service
INFO - TomEE configuration file is 'C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\conf\tomee.xml'
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
INFO - Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
INFO - Creating ServerService(id=cxf)
INFO - Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
INFO -   ** Bound Services **
INFO -   NAME                 IP              PORT  
INFO - -------
INFO - Ready!
INFO - Initialization processed in 2332 ms
INFO - Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
INFO - Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
INFO - Starting service Catalina
INFO - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.3 (7.0.1)
INFO - Deploying configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\conf\Catalina\localhost\Crud.xml
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /Crud
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\T440s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Crud\target\Crud
INFO - Auto-deploying ejb CustomerService: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=CustomerService)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Crud/localDB, type=Resource, provider-id=Default JDBC Database)
INFO - Creating Resource(id=Crud/localDB)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Managed Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Auto-creating a container for bean Crud.Comp911887475: Container(type=MANAGED, id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Creating Container(id=Default Managed Container)
INFO - Using directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\temp for stateful session passivation
INFO - Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/Crud/localDB' in bean Crud.Comp911887475 to Resource(id=Crud/localDB)
INFO - Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/localDB' in bean Crud.Comp911887475 to Resource(id=Crud/localDB)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Stateful Container, type=Container, provider-id=Default Stateful Container)
INFO - Auto-creating a container for bean CustomerService: Container(type=STATEFUL, id=Default Stateful Container)
INFO - Creating Container(id=Default Stateful Container)
INFO - Using directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\temp for stateful session passivation
INFO - Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/Crud/localDB' in bean CustomerService to Resource(id=Crud/localDB)
INFO - Auto-linking resource-ref 'openejb/Resource/localDB' in bean CustomerService to Resource(id=Crud/localDB)
INFO - Configuring PersistenceUnit(name=MyPersistenceUnit, provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider)
INFO - Auto-creating a Resource with id 'Crud/localDBNonJta' of type 'DataSource for 'MyPersistenceUnit'.
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Crud/localDBNonJta, type=Resource, provider-id=Crud/localDB)
INFO - Creating Resource(id=Crud/localDBNonJta)
INFO - Adjusting PersistenceUnit MyPersistenceUnit <jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'Crud/localDB' from 'localDB'
INFO - Adjusting PersistenceUnit MyPersistenceUnit <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'Crud/localDBNonJta' from 'null'
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\Users\T440s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Crud\target\Crud" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\Users\T440s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Crud\target\Crud
INFO - PersistenceUnit(name=MyPersistenceUnit, provider=org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider) - provider time 1391ms
INFO - Jndi(name=CustomerServiceLocalBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerService)
INFO - Jndi(name=global/Crud/CustomerService!com.kuba.crud.service.CustomerService) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerService)
INFO - Jndi(name=global/Crud/CustomerService) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerService)
INFO - Existing thread singleton service in SystemInstance(): org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@6d2a209c
INFO - OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [CdiPlugin]
INFO - Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
INFO - Using annotated mode for file:/C:/Users/T440s/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Crud/target/Crud/WEB-INF/classes/ looking all classes to find CDI beans, maybe think to add a beans.xml if not there or add the jar to exclusions.list
INFO - All injection points were validated successfully.
INFO - OpenWebBeans Container has started, it took 344 ms.
INFO - Created Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerService, ejb-name=CustomerService, container=Default Stateful Container)
INFO - Started Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerService, ejb-name=CustomerService, container=Default Stateful Container)
INFO - using context file C:\Users\T440s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Crud\target\Crud\META-INF\context.xml
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\Users\T440s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Crud\target\Crud)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Using readers:
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.PrimitiveTextProvider@6dc43f2d
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider@2b0a9a37
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider@382667aa
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider@478b110c
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider@3957f0bc
INFO -      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService$TomEEJohnzonProvider@1645bc65
INFO -      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService$TomEEJsonpProvider@26b1fe87
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider@178951ff
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider@5b783974
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider@60e510ea
INFO - Using writers:
INFO -      org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.WadlDocumentMessageBodyWriter@49898fb7
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.StringTextProvider@178951ff
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.PrimitiveTextProvider@6dc43f2d
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.FormEncodingProvider@2b0a9a37
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider@382667aa
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.SourceProvider@478b110c
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider@3957f0bc
INFO -      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService$TomEEJohnzonProvider@1645bc65
INFO -      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRSService$TomEEJsonpProvider@26b1fe87
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider@5b783974
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider@60e510ea
INFO - Using exception mappers:
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper@7d54dc44
INFO -      org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.EJBExceptionMapper@19c575df
INFO -      org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper@494491b6
INFO - REST Application: http://localhost:8080/Crud/               -> org.apache.openejb.server.rest.InternalApplication@46972b9f
INFO -      Service URI: http://localhost:8080/Crud/customers      -> Pojo com.kuba.crud.resources.CustomerResource
INFO -               GET http://localhost:8080/Crud/customers/     ->      List<Customer> getCustomers()
INFO -               GET http://localhost:8080/Crud/customers/{id} ->      Customer getCustomer(int)    
INFO -              POST http://localhost:8080/Crud/customers/     ->      void addCustomer(Customer)   
INFO - Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\conf\Catalina\localhost\Crud.xml has finished in 5,938 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\docs
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /docs
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\docs
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\docs" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\docs
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\docs)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\docs has finished in 187 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /host-manager
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager
INFO - using context file C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager\META-INF\context.xml
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\host-manager has finished in 203 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /manager
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager
INFO - using context file C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\manager has finished in 172 ms
INFO - Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\ROOT
INFO - ------------------------- localhost -> /
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\ROOT
INFO - Enterprise application "C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\ROOT" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\ROOT
INFO - Deployed Application(path=C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\ROOT)
INFO - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO - Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomee-plume-7.0.1\webapps\ROOT has finished in 156 ms
INFO - Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
INFO - Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
INFO - Server startup in 6750 ms
```

Error stack:

```
07-Sep-2016 13:17:05.337 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/Crud] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kuba.crud.resources.CustomerResource.getCustomers(CustomerResource.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you read [the information in](http://tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html) for how to configure your datasource correctly?

Comment: Yes, I've read this. I use org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver instead of EmbeddedDriver. I run Derby inside Netbeans.

Comment: CustomerService seems fine, but the CustomerResource is showing up in the logs "Pojo com.kuba.crud.resources.CustomerResource".  I don't quite know what is generating the statement, but pojos don't usually have properties injected by the container.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I would remove all the javax.persistence.jdbc. properties and just configure the localDB in conf/tomee.xml which is where the datasource configuration belongs to.

Then for your NPE I think the lookup name you reference at the injection point is not right, just remove the name, if the type is enough to do the injection no need to precise it

Comment: EntityManager is still null.

Comment: ok then several things to check: the injected EJB is an EJB instance (the toString() should show something like "proxy=xxxxxx". Then Maybe scope the stateful or dont use a stateful at all (doesnt make much sense for a jaxrs service). Ensure the EJB is scanned properly too if it is not in WEB-INF/classes but a jar in WEB-INF/lib (easy test: rename this jar app.jar)

Comment: Finally I've reinstalled NetBeans and added Derby from Glassfish (provided with NetBeans) and now it works. Maybe there was some problem with jars. This time I haven't play with default NetBeans setup (only changed Derby dir).